# Delete table with empty name in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, drop-table

I'm trying to remove one of my tables stored in PostgreSQL 8.3.8 32bit.

Strange is that my table doesn't have a name, it's empty. Where I do:

```
SELECT * FORM pg_catalog.pg_tables;
```

it says that me tablename name is null.
When I try to delete my table:

```
DROP TABLE sde. ;
```

where sde is my schemaname,
error appears, telling me that there is a syntax error.

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near ";"
LINE 1:drop table sde. ;
```

Is there any way to delete that table?

I also tried that

```
DROP TABLE sde.'';
```

But still error appears.

My table has OID. Is it possible to delete it by OID?

The best solution for me would be renaming that table, that I can save my data from that table.

Comment: Object names need double quotes, not single qutoes. Try: `drop table sde."";`

Comment: If I insert double quotes error appears: `ERROR: zero-length delimited identifier at or near """"
LINE 1: DROP TABLE sde."";`

Comment: Maybe your tablename consists only of whitespace? (so it isn't actually empty, but e.g. one or several spaces)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot create table with empty name:

```
tgr=# create table "" ();
ERROR:  zero-length delimited identifier at or near """"
LINE 1: create table "" ();
```

However you can create a table with a lot of spaces, including newlines:

```
create table "               

                   " ();
```

To work with such table:

1. Find it in `information_schema.tables`
2. Copy/paste table name in some command in double quotes ("")

When the previous fails, you can try to update `pg_class` directly. If you have table OID, try this:

```
update pg_class set relname = 'test'::name where oid = <<YourOID>>;
```

Comment: I found it in `information_schema.tables`, its name looks like this `''`. I've copied it and added double quotes: `DROP TABLE sde."''";`. But error appears telling me that `table "''" does not exist`.

Comment: I see. In 9.1.9 this is ok: `create table sda."''"(); drop table sda."''";` Maybe this is some bug in older PostgreSQL version.

Comment: Do you see this table in pgAdmin? If yes, then you can rename `''` table from there. Right-click on table name and then click on Properties. This also works for me.

Comment: Yes, I see it, but when I try to delete it, message windows appears: `ERROR: syntax error at end of input. LINE 1: drop table sde. `

Comment: What about updating `pg_class` directly? I am not sure if this can have some side-effects, but it works for me. If you have OID then: `update pg_class set relname = 'test'::name where oid = <<YourOID>>;`